# Trying to change a Linux password without using passwd

Tags: linux, security, passwords

I'm a linux noob and I'm stuck on a small detail of a class assignment.

I meant to do this from a root shell:

```
useradd myname -g sudo -p 'openssl passwd -crypt abc123'
```

To create a `sudoer` account for me.

Messed it up the first time, so now it says the user already exists.
I want to make sure I'm in the `sudoers` group and that I know my password to SSH in.

The `passwd` command can't be used, nor the `adduser` command.
I know the `useradd` command is available, but not sure if I can use that somehow...

Ideas?

Edit: And how could I double-check that it worked?

Edit2: I don't have access to an editor like nano or vim :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a work-around:

```
userdel myname
useradd -m -g sudo -p `openssl passwd -1 abc123` myname
```

For some reason, I'm able to use sudo but am not in /etc/sudoers
@paxdiablo, thank you for the help!

Comment: ..garbage text to evade so comment voting detection.. `-1` is old. Use `-6 -salt zyx`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81248/14907

Answer (score 1):

Why not just examine (or edit, given the required powers) the `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/sudoers` files?

Just about everything to do with standard security can be found there

To double check if it works, simply log in from another terminal and try.